# Perfect number method

Tags: java, methods, types, perfect-numbers

This program is supposed to take user input and determine whether or not it is a perfect number. When I try to compile it, I get the error Method testPerfect in class scalvert_Perfect cannot be applied to given types;

- testPerfect(num);
- required :int, int
- found: int
- reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scalvert_Perfect
{
public static void main ( String args[] ) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int test;
    int num = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to test? ");
        test = input.nextInt();

    }while(test < 1);

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a possible perfect number: ");
        num = input.nextInt();

        testPerfect(num);
        printFactors(num);

        counter++;

    }while(counter < test);
}


    public static boolean testPerfect(int num, int test)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < test ; i++)
            {
                if(num % i == 0)
                {
                sum += i;
                }       

            }
                if(sum == num)
                {
                return true;
                }
                else
                {
                return false;
                }
    }       

    public static void printFactors(int num)
    {
        int x;
        int sum = 0;

        for(int factor = num - 1 ; factor > 0; factor--)
            {
                x = num % factor;

                if (x == 0)
                {
                    sum = sum+factor;
                }
            }
                if(sum != num)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%d:NOT PERFECT",num);
                }

            if(sum == num)
                {       
                    System.out.printf("%d: ",num);

                        for(int factor=1; factor < num; factor++)
                            {       
                                x = num % factor;
                                if(x == 0)
                                {
                                    System.out.printf("%d ",factor);
                                }
                            }               
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
                sum = 0;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You function requires two integers because of this:

```
public static boolean testPerfect(int num, int test)
```

You call it with 1 integer here:

```
 testPerfect(num);
```

This is by the way exactly what the error says:

The function:

```
testPerfect(num);
```

Needs two integers

```
required :int, int
```

But you called it with one:

```
found: int
```

So the error is because the amount of arguments is not correct:

```
reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in depth.

Answer (score 1):

The code should pass test to the `testPerfect` method, since the signature of the method is `testPerfect(int,int)`.  The original call is only passing one `int` to the method.

```
 do
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a possible perfect number: ");
        num = input.nextInt();

        testPerfect(num,test);
        printFactors(num);

        counter++;

    }while(counter < test);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
testPerfect(int num, int test)
```

you used one parameter

Answer (score 0):

`testPerfect` methods takes two parameter `int num` and `int test`.

`testPerfect(num);` should produce compiler error as there is no `testPerfect(int)` exists.

you can need to pass two paramer Like `testPerfect(num, test)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function requires two `int` parameters to be passed to it, yet you only pass it one:

```
testPerfect(num);
```

Try passing two to it when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling this:

```
public static boolean testPerfect(int num, int test)
```

like this:

```
testPerfect(num);
```

You are either missing a parameter in your call or asking for too many in your method signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=25;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int v= i*i;
        if(v == n)
        {
            System.out.println("it is a perfect number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ITZ so simple just to compare it

Comment: manish, this checks if a number is the square of an integer, not if it is a perfect number. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number